# Making hierarchical transformation in WebGL

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am making the solar system simulation which simply contains the sun(point light source), the earth and the moon, I can see succesfully these stars on the screen, when I only apply translations to them

Here is the example screen

[image: Example 1]

but as soon as I added the orbit transformaion to the earth, I got this weird result...

[image: Example 2]

It seems that the earth sunddenly stuck in the sun but, at least I can see that somehow the moon is revolving the earth

When I applyed the orbit transformation to the moon also, I got this result..

[image: Example 3]

As you can see that both the earth and the moon stuck in the sun...

Here is the code and the tree how I want their hierarchical transformation to be organized..

```
function RenderPerSec(gl, sun, SunModelMatrix, SunNormalMat, 
  earth, EarthModelMatrix, EarthNormalMat,
  moon, MoonModelMatrix, MoonNormalMat, 
  MvpMatrix, loc_uModelMatrix, loc_uNormalMatrix, loc_uMvpMatrix, 
  loc_uSunTrigger, loc_uEarthTrigger, loc_uMoonTrigger,
  w, h)
{
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


  ///Hierarchical Transformation///


  /*
                     P
                     |
                     V
                     |
                 SUN(Fixed)
                     |
                   EARTH
          Translation from the sun                      
           Rotation around the sun 
              /      |        \ 
tilted 23.5 degree  MOON     Rotation itself
 Along the X-axis    |
         Translation from the earth
          Rotation around the earth
              Rotation itself..

*/

  let MVPStack = [];
  MvpMatrix.setIdentity();


  //Projection
  MvpMatrix.setPerspective(60, w/h, 1, 1000);
  //View
  MvpMatrix.lookAt(0, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

  //Model Transforms...

  //Sun

  SunModelMatrix.setTranslate(0, 0, 0);

  MvpMatrix.multiply(SunModelMatrix);

  MVPStack.push(new Matrix4(MvpMatrix));


  gl.uniform1i(loc_uSunTrigger, 1);
  gl.uniform1i(loc_uEarthTrigger, 0);
  gl.uniform1i(loc_uMoonTrigger, 0);

  RenderSun(gl, sun, SunModelMatrix, SunNormalMat, MvpMatrix, loc_uModelMatrix, loc_uNormalMatrix, loc_uMvpMatrix);

  //Earth, translation and rotation 23.5 along the X-axis, rotation itself
  EarthModelMatrix.setTranslate(5, 0, 0); //Translation from the sun
  EarthModelMatrix.setRotate(CURRENT_EATHR_REVOLVING_ANGLE, 0, 1, 0); //Revolving around the sun

  MvpMatrix = MVPStack.pop();
  MvpMatrix.multiply(EarthModelMatrix);

  MVPStack.push(new Matrix4(MvpMatrix));

  gl.uniform1i(loc_uSunTrigger, 0);
  gl.uniform1i(loc_uEarthTrigger, 1);
  gl.uniform1i(loc_uMoonTrigger, 0);

  RenderEarth(gl, earth, EarthModelMatrix, EarthNormalMat, MvpMatrix, loc_uModelMatrix, loc_uNormalMatrix, loc_uMvpMatrix);


  //Moon, translation and rotation itself
  MoonModelMatrix.setTranslate(2.5, 0, 0);
  MoonModelMatrix.setRotate(CURRENT_MOON_REVOLVING_ANGLE, 0, 1, 0);

  MvpMatrix = MVPStack.pop();
  MvpMatrix.multiply(MoonModelMatrix, EarthModelMatrix);

  gl.uniform1i(loc_uSunTrigger, 0);
  gl.uniform1i(loc_uEarthTrigger, 0);
  gl.uniform1i(loc_uMoonTrigger, 1);

  RenderMoon(gl, moon, MoonModelMatrix, MoonNormalMat, MvpMatrix, loc_uModelMatrix, loc_uNormalMatrix, loc_uMvpMatrix);
}
```

if I remove **setRotate** functions in this code I can get the first result..

and here is the render function

```
function RenderSun(gl, sun, SunModelMatrix, SunNormalMat, MvpMatrix, loc_uModelMatrix, loc_uNormalMatrix, loc_uMvpMatrix)
{
  gl.bindVertexArray(sun.vao);


  SunNormalMat.setInverseOf(SunModelMatrix);
  SunNormalMat.transpose();

  // Pass the model matrix to uModelMatrix
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uModelMatrix, false, SunModelMatrix.elements);

  // Pass the model view projection matrix to umvpMatrix
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uMvpMatrix, false, MvpMatrix.elements);

  // Pass the transformation matrix for normals to uNormalMatrix
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uNormalMatrix, false, SunNormalMat.elements);

  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, sun.n, sun.type, 0);
}

function RenderEarth(gl, earth, EarthModelMatrix, EarthNormalMat, MvpMatrix, loc_uModelMatrix, loc_uNormalMatrix, loc_uMvpMatrix)
{
  gl.bindVertexArray(earth.vao);

  EarthNormalMat.setInverseOf(EarthModelMatrix);
  EarthNormalMat.transpose();

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uModelMatrix, false, EarthModelMatrix.elements);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uMvpMatrix, false, MvpMatrix.elements);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uNormalMatrix, false, EarthNormalMat.elements);

  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, earth.n, earth.type, 0);
}

function RenderMoon(gl, moon, MoonModelMatrix, MoonNormalMat, MvpMatrix, loc_uModelMatrix, loc_uNormalMatrix, loc_uMvpMatrix)
{
  gl.bindVertexArray(moon.vao);

  MoonNormalMat.setInverseOf(MoonModelMatrix);
  MoonNormalMat.transpose();

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uModelMatrix, false, MoonModelMatrix.elements);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uMvpMatrix, false, MvpMatrix.elements);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc_uNormalMatrix, false, MoonNormalMat.elements);

  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, moon.n, moon.type, 0);
}
```

I am using a stack to implement the hierarchical transformations... could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an article on this [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html) and stack based one [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html)

In general you would need to do something like

```
push(0,0,0)
  push(sun rotation)
    draw sun
  pop()  // sun rotation
  push(earth orbit rotation)
    push(earth translation)
      push(earth rotation)
        draw earth
      pop() // earth rotation
      push(moon orbit rotation)
        push(moon translation)
          push(moon rotation)
            draw moon
          pop()  // moon rotation
        pop()  // moon translation
      pop()  // moon orbit rotation
    pop()  // earth translation
  pop()  // earth orbit rotation
pop()  // center of solar system
```

Your matrix math library is not familar to me but functions named `setTranslate` and `setRotate` do not sound like the appropriate functions. They sound like they set translation or set the rotation rather than multiply an existing matrix by a translation matrix or a rotation matrix.

In most 3D math libraries to make a sphere appear at some distance from the center of rotation it would be something like

```
  mathlib.translate(centerOfRotation)  // move 0,0,0 to center of rotation
  mathlib.rotate(orbitRotation)        // rotate space
  mathlib.translate(orbitRadius)       // move some distance from center in rotated space
```

Or a longer form

```
  mat = identity();
  mat = mathlib.multiply(mat, mathlib.translation(centerOfRotation))
  mat = mathlib.multiply(mat, mathlib.rotatation(orbitRotation))
  mat = mathlib.multiply(mat, mathlib.translation(orbitRadius))
```

If it's a auto stacking library then the shorter form would have already stacked 3 matrices.

Note since the only part you seem to be having issues with is the matrix stack part here's some code using a matrix stack to compute the 3 matrices (sun, earth, moon) and then it uses those matrices with 2D canvas (which you can ignore)

```js
'use strict';
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
const m4 = twgl.m4;

const stack = [];
const current = () => stack[stack.length - 1];
const pop = () => stack.pop();
const identity = () => stack.push(m4.identity());
const translate = (t) => stack.push(m4.translate(current(), t));
const rotate = (axis, r) => stack.push(m4.axisRotate(current(), axis, r));
const zAxis = [0, 0, 1];

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001; // convert to seconds
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(ctx.canvas);
  const {width, height} = ctx.canvas;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  
  let sunMat;
  let earthMat;
  let moonMat;
  
  identity();
    // translate to center of solar system
    translate([width / 2, height / 2, 0]);
      rotate(zAxis, time * 4);  // sun rotation
        sunMat = current();
      pop();  // sun rotation
  
      rotate(zAxis, time / 2) // push(earth orbit rotation)
        translate([height / 4, 0, 0]); //push(earth translation)
          rotate(zAxis, time * 8); // push(earth rotation)
            earthMat = current();  //
          pop(); // earth rotation
          rotate(zAxis, time * 2); //push(moon orbit rotation)
            translate([height / 8, 0, 0]); // push(moon translation)
              rotate(zAxis, time * 16); //push(moon rotation)
                moonMat = current(); 
              pop();  // moon rotation
            pop();  // moon translation
          pop();  // moon orbit rotation
        pop();  // earth translation
      pop();  // earth orbit rotation
    pop();  // center of solar system  
  pop();  // identity
  
  drawSquare(sunMat, 40, 'orange');
  drawSquare(earthMat, 20, 'blue');
  drawSquare(moonMat, 10, 'gray');

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);

function drawSquare(mat, size, color) {
  ctx.setTransform(mat[0], mat[1], mat[4], mat[5], mat[12], mat[13]);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.strokeRect(-size / 2, -size / 2, size, size);
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

here's one with explicit push

```js
'use strict';
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
const m4 = twgl.m4;

const stack = [m4.identity()];
const current = () => stack[stack.length - 1];
const currentCopy = () => stack[stack.length - 1].slice();
const push = () => stack.push(currentCopy());
const pop = () => stack.pop();
const identity = () => m4.identity(current());
const translate = (t) => m4.translate(current(), t, current());
const rotate = (axis, r) => m4.axisRotate(current(), axis, r, current());
const zAxis = [0, 0, 1];

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001; // convert to seconds
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(ctx.canvas);
  const {width, height} = ctx.canvas;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  
  let sunMat;
  let earthMat;
  let moonMat;
  
  push();
  // translate to center of solar system
  translate([width / 2, height / 2, 0]);
    push();
      rotate(zAxis, time * 4);  // sun rotation
      sunMat = currentCopy();
    pop();  // sun rotation

    rotate(zAxis, time / 2) // earth orbit rotation
    translate([height / 4, 0, 0]); // earth translation
    
    push();
      rotate(zAxis, time * 8); // earth rotation
      earthMat = currentCopy();  //
    pop(); // earth rotation
 
    push();
      rotate(zAxis, time * 2); // moon orbit rotation
      translate([height / 8, 0, 0]); // moon translation
      rotate(zAxis, time * 16); // moon rotation
      moonMat = currentCopy(); 
    pop(); 
  pop();  
  
  drawSquare(sunMat, 40, 'orange');
  drawSquare(earthMat, 20, 'blue');
  drawSquare(moonMat, 10, 'gray');

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);

function drawSquare(mat, size, color) {
  ctx.setTransform(mat[0], mat[1], mat[4], mat[5], mat[12], mat[13]);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.strokeRect(-size / 2, -size / 2, size, size);
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, Your explanatios are really helpful!